# Find the name and bio account of Telegram in telethon

Tags: python, api, telegram, telethon

With the help of the following commands, a contact is added to the Telegram account and I extract the username from it.

```
def check(phone_number):
    try:
        contact = InputPhoneContact(client_id = 0, phone = phone_number, first_name="__test__", last_name="__last_test__")
        contacts = client(functions.contacts.ImportContactsRequest([contact]))
        username = contacts.to_dict()['users'][0]['username']
        dell = client(functions.contacts.DeleteContactsRequest(id=[username]))
        return username
        
    except:
        res = "__err__"
        return res
```

As you can see in the commands above, the `first_name` and `last_name` values are `__test__` and `__last_test__`

The user has defined a name and bio for the account. But I was not able to extract them like a username. Also, after deleting the contact, the defined name will be displayed in the telegram. But I do not know how to extract it. How can I see the name and bio that the user has defined for the account?

Comment: https://tl.telethon.dev/methods/users/get_full_user.html